# How to use 'this' with the with handlebars helper in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to do something like this to no avail:

```
{{#each item in controller}}

    {{#with this as item.request}}
        my name is: {{name}}
    {{/with}}

{{/each}}
```

Is there a workaround here?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It feels like there should be an item itemController that is backed by a model.  In which case the with context you are trying to achieve would already be the established context of the backing model.  Try looking at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html and see if the lower part on itemController helps?

Comment: although I agree it would be better to use itemController, it's more easily said than done in the legacy code base i'm working with specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. It should be the following:

```
    {{#each item in controller}}
      {{#with item.request}}
        my name is: {{name}}
      {{/with}}
    {{/each}}
```

Here is the link to the working example on jsbin - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/huwizafevo/1/edit